# How long time to travel distance? Teacher and I disagree?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration

This is the problem:

> Assume that the maximum linear velocity and the maximum linear acceleration of the car are given by
> $V_{max} = 2 m/s$ and $a_{max} = 3 m/s^2$, respectively. Assuming a trapezoidal velocity profile, find the minimum travelling
> time for the trajectory for traveling 3m.

My reasoning:
I assume we do not have to end at a stand still, we therefore give full throttle for all distance.

First we need to accelerate:
The time taken to accelerate from 0 to 2 m/s when a=3 is $t=\frac{2}{3}s$. The distance this covers is $s=at^2=3(\frac{2}{3})^2=\frac{4}{3}m$. We therefore need to travel $3-\frac{4}{3}=1.66m$ at 2m/s which will take $\frac{1.66}{2}=0.8333$. Total time is therefore $0.8333+\frac{2}{3} = 1.5s$.

My teachers solution, I  do not fully understand but he got 2.16s:

[image]

Am I thinking completely wrong? My method is pretty much what I learned in physics, but I do not understand why it would not work, or does my teacher have the wrong answer?

Comment: Whilst undergoing constant acceleration, $s\ne at^2$ but rather $s=\frac 12 at^2$

Comment: The problem is that the cited problem doesn't state what either initial or terminal velocity is. So, I'd answer *the minimum travelling time is 1 second* (assuming full speed before and after covering the 3 m). The rectangular velocity profile is also trapezoidal, just a special case.

Comment: Initial velocity is 0

Comment: The teacher's equations can be written as
$$
h=v_{max}t_f-v_{max}T_a\,.
$$
Looks pretty weird. Apart from the factor $1/2$ you missed in $s=\frac{1}{2}at^2$ as pointed out by Farcher your solution is correct. You should get $1.8333$ seconds.

Comment: The requirement of a trapezoidal velocity profile eliminates the possibility of a full throttle acceleration for all distance.  In my opinion, that velocity profile strongly implies that the car started from rest and ended at rest.

Comment: @KurtG. I managed to get 1.833s, thank you, I completely missed that error. However the teacher still get another result, are the teacher wrong?

Comment: @J.Doe . David White just made some important comment. Your velocity profile is a linear ly increasing one. Please discuss with your teacher if that's trapezoidal or not. It is a matter of clarifying that point. Nothing that PSE users could resolve I think. (To me your profile is trapezoidal and your solution correct. Perhaps for your teacher your profile is not trapezoidal.)

Answer (score 2):

A velocity against time graph can sometimes provide a good overview of a problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research and found a lecture where the teacher goes through a similar example with the same formulas. The teachers answer is wrong, because he have completely ignored the distance the robot travels while accelerating. The teachers answer is basically: how long time to drive 3m at 2m/s + the time to accelerate to 2m/s without taking the distance during acceleration into account. Thank you for your help, and also the figure Farcher drew is correct. I am not sure if this question will help anyone else, but maybe the moral of the story should be that, even the teacher is a human, and humans make errors